# Can walking be a way to lose weight

Tags: weight-loss, walking

After running my knees will be hurting, I will stop running after that, but still I want to lose weight.

When I start running, I mostly alternate between running and walking, it would be 30 minutes by then.

After that I can't run anymore, so can I walk? How useful is that for burning the fat?

Comment: Walking is still exercise. Although, your diet will more largely determine your ability to burn fat and lose weight.

Answer (score 9):

Every mile you walk burns about 100 calories.  The farther you walk, the more calories you burn.  So yes, you can still burn fat and lose weight with a good walking program.   You can even do some interval training with your walking, by speeding up for short intervals and then slowing back down to your normal pace.

As to your knee pain while running, it can often be lessened with improvements in footwear, running technique and exercises to balance your lower extremities through stretching and strengthening.  For example, tight calf muscles,  hamstrings, IT bands, quads, hip rotators, flexors and adductors can cause alignment problems that are aggravated with the impact of running.   Strengthening of your calf muscles, quads, hams and glutes will help absorb the impact of running so that your knee joints absorbs less shock.  However, while these measures can help, they won’t necessarily eliminate pain with running, esp. if you have joint or cartilage damage.

Alternatives to running - Walking is a great exercise if done consistently.  Adding [nordic walking poles](http://www.HowToGetBackInShape.com/Nordic-Pole-Walking.html) to your walk can increase your calorie burn by incorporating more muscle groups of the trunk and arms.  At the same time the poles allow you to transfer some of your weight off of your knees and get a better stride.

Elliptical trainers, swimming and cycling allow you to get a good workout with little to no impact to your knees.  You can also get a good workout by running or jogging in water with or without resistance bands with minimal impact to your joints.  The deeper the water, the less the impact.

For strengthening, stair climbing whether up or down, and squats may bother your knees depending on the origin of pain. Using equipment like a total gym or an [exercise ball](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOs9OYV9CX8) can help you strengthen your legs as they let you perform a squat with some support.

Hope that helps.  And of course, hydrate well and eat a healthy diet.   Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you should use good pair of shoe and check your body weight before trying to run longer distance rather before running only, otherwise it can be detrimental to your progress(burning fat).

You can climb up and down stairways, do skipping, etc along with these(running and walking) to burn fat

And also
Do some weight training. If you don't want to go to gym, trying doing exercises at home with
items available.

Comment: Weight training is always my number one suggestion for people trying to lose weight. Even if you don't want to bulk up, people constantly underestimate the number of calories that a little extra muscle burns through the course of a day. Not to mention the benefit of improved lifestyle (being able to pick your kid up, lift a heavy box, or move a table without straining). All of this can be accomplished without turning into the Incredible Hulk.

Comment: @Aardvark +1 muscle burns serious energy.

Answer (score 5):

80% of weight loss is through your diet.  However, for that last 20% a low heart rate workout such as swift walking will help you burn more fat than a high heart rate workout.

If knee pain is a problem, you might want to do something lower impact such as an elliptical for your cardio work.  NOTE: going *up* stairs is a good workout that will strengthen the knees some, but going *down* stairs will add a lot more stress to them than running.

Weight training, and specifically full barbell squats will strengthen your knees better than anything else.  Just start with the bar and go up 5 lbs per workout as long as you can (3x per week).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, walking will help lose weight. As you get older, you may find yourself able to run less and less (before the onset of knee pain), so continuing walking will be helpful as exercise.

I find that the difference between daily 30-45 min of walking (I have a desk job) and 0min walking is about 5-7 pounds (or maybe you'd rather prefer this explained as "if I walk 30-45 minutes per day, after about 2-3 months, my baseline weight is about 5-7 pounds lighter than when I have no time to walk at all"). When I was carless, I had to walk about 90-120 minutes daily as part of my commuting and was about 20 pounds lighter than when I later got a car and was able to drive everywhere. Your experience will probably be different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally long walks burn a lot of calories, the only thing you'll burn more is extreme sport (such as long-distance runs).

When walking, you'll burn calories not only from distance, but also from temperature difference (in cold winter). When I was on moving camp, I've burned about 6000 kcal a day, but this was distance about 20-30 'normalized' km (1km+100m up) with heavy rucksacks and staying the whole day&night outside. The calories usage was measured by professional devices (from university).